# burninate "solutions"

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

[solutions](/questions/tagged/solutions) looks like a meaningless tag, which could be applied to every single question on the site; why would the person asking a question *not* want a solution?

I propose burnination with extreme prejudice.

Following Bart's comment, came up with the following:

Where [solutions](/questions/tagged/solutions) is used with respect to Visual Studio, it should be re-tagged as [solution](/questions/tagged/solution), which has a tag wiki inidicating it's about VS Solution files.

[solution-files](/questions/tagged/solution-files), [solution-folders](/questions/tagged/solution-folders), and [solution-structure](/questions/tagged/solution-structure) should also probably be retagged to [solution](/questions/tagged/solution)

[typical-solutions](/questions/tagged/typical-solutions) and [preferred-solution](/questions/tagged/preferred-solution) look like complete junk.

Comment: Seems to be a used a fair number of times for Visual Studio solutions, but perhaps that can do with a more descriptive name if it's needed at all.

Comment: The "solution" tag wiki indicates it's for just that purpose; I'll retag the VS questions. (And cleanup that tag because it's massively misused.)

Comment: Downvoters care to defend these tags?

Answer (score 5):

Some of those questions were hard to retag, but most seemed to relate to [equation-solving](/questions/tagged/equation-solving) and [solution](/questions/tagged/solution), and I have thus re-tagged all that remained.

I also have merged the [sln](/questions/tagged/sln) with [solution](/questions/tagged/solution), as the SLN tag seemed redundant.

The tag should disappear in 24 hours, and seeing as it wasn't a very active tag, I don't expect it to come back any time soon, so burnination, while awesome, probably isn't needed here.